global-ish object groups in python
I need to keep track of groups of objects, which I want to access from anywhere in my code.
this is my 5 minute solution:
# this is in the __init__.py of the main directory of the package. 
# I import just the functions in all the other modules where i need to access the groups

_groups = {}


def add_to_group(group_name: str, thing) -> None:
    if group_name in _groups.keys():
        _groups[group_name].append(thing)
    else:
        _groups[group_name] = [thing]


def remove_from_group(group_name: str, thing) -> None:
    if group_name in _groups.keys():
        ix = _groups[group_name].index(thing)
        _groups[group_name].pop(ix)
    else:
        raise NameError(f"group_name '{group_name}' was not found in groups. group names found were {_groups.keys()}")


def get_all_in_group(group_name: str) -> list:
    return _groups.get(group_name, [])


def delete_group(group_name: str) -> list:
    return _groups.pop(group_name)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_thing = 5
    add_to_group("stuff", my_thing)
    add_to_group("more_stuff", my_thing)
    print(get_all_in_group("stuff"))
    remove_from_group("stuff", my_thing)
    print(get_all_in_group("stuff"))
    delete_group("stuff")
    print(_groups)
    remove_from_group("stuff", my_thing)


I'm wondering:

do yall ever do this?

does something like this already exist, or maybe there is a more 'pythonic' way of doing it? (i know about global vars, just trying to avoid them)

are there any obvious downsides or pitfalls to this approach?


I'm aware of the errors that would be caused by passing group names that don't exist
also aware that things could get funky placing duplicate or equivalent objects in the same group. in my use case everything should be unique.

What stops you from using the lists in the rest of the code instead of the names of those lists?  If those names appear as external input, perhaps the dictionary could be local to the parsing code.

@DavisHerring ill admit I could totally be overthinking it. but I prob need to create groups dynamically. I could just pass around the dictionary, but this abstraction just makes me feel safer for some reason. im using a UI lib and have code organized in to functions to create widgets and handle callbacks. theres a lot so I need to organize into different files, but I like to keep everything as pure as possible. somehow keeping the ways that all this disparate code interacts with the same data more strict just feels right

Providing that all objects you put into groups are hashable and that order of insertion doesn't matter you can simply use a defaultdict of sets instead for the purpose.
Your sample code can then become:
from collections import defaultdict

groups = defaultdict(set)
my_thing = 5
groups["stuff"].add(my_thing)
groups["more_stuff"].add(my_thing)
print(groups["stuff"])
groups["stuff"].remove(my_thing)
print(groups["stuff"])
del groups["stuff"]
print(groups)
groups["stuff"].remove(my_thing)

If some of the objects are unhashable or if the order of insertion is important, you can use a defaultdict of lists instead, in which case you would use list.append to add an object and list.remove to remove one.

Thanks for the response! didnt know about this.
the *_group() functions are less about making sure theres a default, and more for restricting the ways that code will interact with _groups, which will act as sort of a registry of objects. I also need code at all different levels of scope to have access to same information without using global variables.

I see. The code you have in the question is fine for the purpose. There's nothing wrong with global variables as long as they aren't reassigned in a function. "Global" variables aren't truly global in Python as they are only names in the namespace of the module in which they are defined, so your other modules may import your "groups" module without worrying about namespace pollution.
